# MySQL Privileges to CREATE DATABASE/SCHEMA for the user with default rights

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database, singlestore

I am investigating user privileges in a MySQL database.

```
CREATE USER 'reader' IDENTIFIED BY 'reader';
```

As per MySQL documentation, the user gets created with the least privilege--SELECT.

How is it possible that they are able to use a CREATE DATABASE/SCHEMA statement? I use a MySQL instance in the official Docker image, and I did not find any mention of OS differences.

If it's just documentation obsoletion, how do I create a user that can have just read access to the database objects, mainly on the `information_schema` or `sys` schemas?

Comment: This is unclear. What is your 1 specific question? "How is it possible that they are able to use" Are you trying to say that it is possible? Or are you asking for the way to do it? "OS differences" What OS differences? Between what OSs? What does that have to do with your question? "If it's just documentation obsoletion" What is "it"? Lack of mention of how in documentation? Is "obsoletion" (obsolesence?) the word you mean? It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The least privileges is `USAGE`, not `SELECT`. Using `MYSQL_{USER,PASSWORD,DATABASE}` will create a user with all privs on the database.

Information schema is readable by anyone, however the database objects visible are only those the user has access too.

Access to the `sys` schema requires a `GRANT SELECT ON sys.* TO user`. As the `sys` schema is a view on the `performance_schema`, `GRANT SELECT ON performance_schema.* TO user` is also required.